# Pass multiple data field items to subreport | Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a data field in my main report which finds multiple information:

[Found data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Xbl.png)

Now I want to pass all these information to my sub report.
I already tried that with linking the relevant data field to each other using the subreport link.

The problem is, that I can only find the last information from my main report. Crystal does not pass all information - just the last one.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What section of your report is the sub-report located within?  What are the grouping levels for your report?

Answer (score 0):

Use an SHARED array variable.

Shared variable declared and populated in the main report are accessible within subreport formulas (provided the subreport is located in a section BELOW the main report section where the shared variable was populated).

Comment: Can you give me an example for that?
Lets assume that my data field has the name [PLACEHOLDER] in the main and sub report.